# Display:none items still retaining space on the page

Tags: html, css, media-queries, flexbox

I have six items in a 100%-width [carousel](https://jsfiddle.net/0oug0t3r/). When the screen is in portrait orientation, I'd like only 3 items to appear, so i dropped 3 using a media query (here is the jfiddle with the complete [script](https://jsfiddle.net/0oug0t3r/)):

```
 @media all and (orientation:portrait) {

    .wrapper4 .carousel1{
        display: none;
    }

    .wrapper4 .carousel3{
        display: none;
    }

    .wrapper4 .carousel6{
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The 3 items disappear, but the space they occupy is still retained. And when I try to get the remaining items to fill out the space that was previously occupied, it doesn't work.

```
.wrapper4 .carousel {
    flex: 1; min-width: 33.3333%;
}
```

ie. above doesn't help spread out the remaining items. The 3 remaining items in the carousel retain their size and there's blank space occupied by the previous items when the screen is contracted to mimic portrait mode. How can I get the space to be freed up and the remaining items to fill up this space?

Comment: Without seeing your carousel script this is hard to answer, but, did you tell your carousel to only show 3 when you hid the others? If you hide that's no good as it probably thinks they're still there

Comment: Yes - the code is there in the fiddle linked in the question: https://jsfiddle.net/0oug0t3r/

Comment: @Darren above is what I passed in the media query, and with that, the remaining three that have not been mentioned show up - the problem is that the space occupied by the display: none items are being retained, and i'm looking for a way to make it look like those 3 items don't exist; the remaining 3 items should fill up the width.

Comment: I've made a tweak to your fiddle so the media query works on width instead of orientation - which I imagine makes more sense. The extra columns show and hide correctly and the layout updates as one would expect. I can only think that on whatever device you are testing the orientation change isn't triggering a relayout, which is odd considering that it is updating visibility. https://jsfiddle.net/3eLj47te/4/

Comment: @Matthew, I tried it, but the problem remains - the spaces of the undisplayed items are still retained. also `img {
  display: none;
  width: 100% !important;
}` interferes with the proportions of the images. btw, am viewing this on a laptop-chrome browser.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on Chrome in Samsung Note, this works as intended:

---

All carousel items disappear in portrait mode:

```
@media all and ( orientation: portrait ) {

    .carousel1 { display: none; }
    .carousel2 { display: none; }
    .carousel3 { display: none; }
    .carousel4 { display: none; }
    .carousel5 { display: none; }
    .carousel6 { display: none; }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0oug0t3r/11/ (can also be tested on desktop by re-sizing window)

---

All carousel items disappear in landscape mode:

```
@media all and ( orientation: landscape ) {

    .carousel1 { display: none; }
    .carousel2 { display: none; }
    .carousel3 { display: none; }
    .carousel4 { display: none; }
    .carousel5 { display: none; }
    .carousel6 { display: none; }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0oug0t3r/12/

---

Removing the three carousel items as described in the question:

```
@media all and ( orientation: portrait ) {

    .carousel1 { display: none; }
    .carousel3 { display: none; }
    .carousel6 { display: none; }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0oug0t3r/13/

---

The only adjustments made were to match the `alt` tags in the `img` element with the corresponding carousel `ID` number, and I simplified the selector.

Comment: Thanks @Michael - I tried this and other tweeks on the media query, for some reason, it still kept the space that was occupied by the display: none items. In the end I created another wrapper in the html identical to wrapper4, but with only 3 items. I kept that hidden in landscape and revealed it in the place of wrapper 4 in portrait. not sure at all though why it wasn't working otherwise. may have to do with flexbox being used (as i am with this code).

Comment: That's interesting. Everything works fine on this end. I am able to remove individual carousel items (including the space they occupy), using portrait, landscape and width expressions. Works on mobile and desktop.

Comment: am thinking it does have to do with a flexbox conflict (how should a flex-item deal with display:none) - i'd share a snapshot of how it looked before the fix with an identical wrapper (can't seem to add here) it basically looks like a nice band of images with gaps in between showing only the background color.

Comment: I've never had an issue with `display: none` and flex properties. Maybe it's something new. If it's a bug, consider reviewing/posting here: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs